# Iterate to find out whether a square is the "identity" - java treemaps

Tags: java, treemap

```
public class Square {
private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> square;
private final int height;
private final int width;

public Square(int h, int w) {
    this.square = new TreeMap<>();
    this.height = h;
    this.width =  w;
} 
    public boolean isIdentity() {
    boolean isIdentity = false;
    for (Integer key1 : square.keySet()) { // First integer key of treemap (row)
        for (Integer key2 : square.keySet()) { // Second integer key (column)
            for(TreeMap<Integer, Double> value : matrix.values()) {
                if ((key1.intValue() == key2.intValue()) && (key2.intValue() == 1.0)) {
                    isIdentity = true;
                }
                else {
                    isIdentity = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isIdentity;
    }
```

I'm trying to see is the square is going to be an identity square (below). The problem I'm having is (I think) lining up the "keys" correctly. In my mind, the double value at (key1 / key2 ) should be 1.0

Identity:

```
1000000
0100000
0010000
0001000
0000100
0000010
0000001
```

(keySet() is null? )

Testing:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

        HashMap<String,Square> square =
                new HashMap<String,Square>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a command: ");
        String cmd = input.next();
        while (!cmd.equals("end")) {
            if (cmd.equals("new")) {
                String name = input.next();
                int rows = input.nextInt();
                int cols = input.nextInt();
                if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) {
                    System.out.println("new: rows and/or cols less than 1: ");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                Square m = new Square(rows,cols);
                int i = input.nextInt();
                while (i >= 0) {
                    int j = input.nextInt();
                    double v = input.nextDouble();
                    m.set(i,j,v);
                    i = input.nextInt();
                }
                square.put(name,m);
                System.out.printf("new %s = %s\n", name, m);
            }

    if (cmd.equals("isIdentity")) {
                String which = input.next();
                if (!square.containsKey(which)) {
                    System.out.println("isIdentity: no such matrix: " + which);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                System.out.printf("%s.isIdentity() = %b\n",
                        which, square.get(which).isIdentity());
            }

        }

    } // end of main method
```

Test input as such:

```
Enter a command:
new one 1000 2000
   0 0 1.0
   50 834 5.0
   -1

Enter a command:
isIdentity one
```

Comment: Please  eloberate your problem . I didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Why are you using a `TreeMap` as opposed to a 2D array?

Comment: I'm using a treemap, because the values in these keys can be removed and added as pleased (other parts of code). For this particular method, I am trying to see if the pattern of the treemap will be the same as that of an identity matrix. (row/column value = 1).

Comment: what is matrix reference refers to?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan More code added

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
(key1.intValue() == key2.intValue()) && (key2.intValue() == 1.0)
```

looks off. what you are saying is that the keys should have the same value and that value should also be 1. You probably want the second `key2.intValue()` to be `value.get(key2)` instead

Edit: also you should return false instead of `isIdentity = false;`. take the matrix

```
00
01
```

your code will first see the 0 and set `isIdentity` to false. the second it will se 1 and set it to true. finally it will return true instead of false like it should. The moment it finds a non-oneelment it should stop immeaditely as you know it cannot be an identity matrix.

Comment: How would this take in consideration the isIdentity = true? Would an if statement suffice to say whether isIdentity = true return true else return false?

Comment: I would remove `isIdentity` all together and change the if to `if (!contents_of_if) return false;`. then at the end, you know you've checked all of them must be 1 if you haven't returned yet so return true.

Comment: Thank you. Another question if I may... When running through the test driver it states the .keySet() is null, would a method returning that instance of the square help solve this? (Not very good with maps yet)

Comment: Tester driver was added... Not understanding "null" keySet when testing